# Is there a way to open documents stored in my aws server using google doc service?

Tags: google-drive-api, cherrypy

I don't want my documents stored on Google Drive, but instead all those documents reside in aws server. When clicking, it ideally should retrieve the document's content and metadata, send them to google's api, and return a url which I can send to frontend and open up a new tab to view that document.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort answer no. Long answer if you insert a document with [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) or you end up using Google Documents then the document will be created on your Google Drive as it is the place where Google Docs are stored (and they [contribute towards Drive storage quotas](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/9312312?hl=en#:%7E:text=About%20Google%20Account%20storage,One%20membership%20(where%20available).)).